# What is the alternative for casting onALarmlistener in android API level 24 for API 21

Tags: android, alarmmanager

This is my code

```
alarmStart = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmStart.set(AlarmManager.RTC,startTime.getTime(),"alarm",
new AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener() 
             {
                @Override
                public void onAlarm() {                      
                    //On alarm code here
                }
             },null);
```

It says that cast to OnAlarmListener requires API level 24(current min is 21).
But i want it to run on all API >=21. What changes should i make in my code?

Comment: use FirebaseJobDispatcher.

Comment: cant i use the basic alarm manager for the same without using FirebaseJobDispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.OnAlarmListener.html) (emphasis mine):

> Direct-notification alarms: **the requester must be running continuously
>   from the time the alarm is set to the time it is delivered, or
>   delivery will fail.** Only one-shot alarms can be set using this
>   mechanism, not repeating alarms.

IMO this is just some kind of wrapper around [Messenger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger) or the like.

You could implement similar feature by embedding a Messenger (which will execute your onAlarm code) into your PendingIntent, and call it when your PendingIntent goes off.